# GIT - stop tracking file without removing it from server

Tags: git, .htaccess

I have two project instances - local and production (without access to apache settings).

In project I use GIT Version Control.
I would like to prepare .htaccess file, where small part of it, should be executed only on production.

I wonder how to remove this .htaccess file from GIT tracking after sending correct .htaccess to production. Then on local version I can comment out some lines of .htaccess code.

I know that in htaccess I can use `if directive` and `git rm --cached` (but it also removed file form production).

Now I need to know how by GIT stop tracking file without removing it from server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Git it is fairly tricky, and probably not good practice, to have files which are versioned sometime, and not versioned other times.  Does this `.htaccess` need to be versioned at all, and if so, why?

Comment: On production I force https, on localhost I do not need that.

Comment: Sounds like you want to have either two separate builds or branches for those situations.

Comment: I'm going to close this as the duplicate that phd linked, but consider *not* using Git as a deployment tool, or at least, not directly: your deployment tool could extract one commit using `git archive` and then *modify it to behave as desired based on the deployment location*, so that you don't need to be concerned with the `.htaccess` contents as committed as those are not used at all.